# validate jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, datepicker

i am looking for how to validate that user has selected a date or not. if he didn't selected a date form date picker he should be notified to select the date. 
i'm using jQuery datepicker. script i'm using is

```
 <script>


 $(function() {
    $( "#inputdate2" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
  });
  </script>
```

and in the html

```
 <p id="date2">
Date From:<input type="text" name="datefrom" id="inputdate2" readonly="readonly" ></p>
```

Comment: $("#inputdate2").val() will be false if no input is given so you can just do if that thing returns false then give user an alert or error message, also set your input to readonly="readonly" so users can't enter text or random numbers in the input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDITED : 
You can following my code below :
HTML

```
Date From : <input type="text" name="datefrom" id="inputdate2" required>
<button type="button" id="btn"> Submit </button>
```

JS

```
 $(function() {
 $("#inputdate2").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });

 $("#btn").on('click', function(){
    if($("#inputdate2").val() == '')
    {
        alert("Please Select Date First!");
    }
 });
```

});

you can check my result from JSFiddle --> http://jsfiddle.net/4e1radwm/1/

UPDATE :

this is for @babar scenario :

> scenerio is i've two dates picker. inputdate1 and inputdate2. if i add this function i.e firstCheck() to both dates script so i'll be notified twice to enter date, if i didnt enter date. I want to be notified only once

HTML

```
Date From : <input type="text" name="datefrom" id="inputdate1" required> 
To : <input type="text" name="dateto" id="inputdate2" required>
    <button type="button" id="btn"> Submit </button>
```

JS

```
$(function() {

     $("#inputdate1").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
     $("#inputdate2").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }); 

     $("#btn").on('click', function(){
        if($("#inputdate1").val() == '' || $("#inputdate2").val() == '')
        {
            alert("Please Select Date First!");
        }
     });
});
```

you can check my result from JSFiddle --> http://jsfiddle.net/fjj20euw/

I hope my answers help you!

Comment: your solutions helped me . but the scenerio is i've two dates picker. inputdate1 and inputdate2. if i add this function i.e firstCheck() to both dates script so i'll be notified twice to enter date, if i didnt enter date. 

I want to be notified only once.

Answer (score 1):

$("#inputdate").val() will return false if there is no value, therefore putting the not operator "!" in front of it you can check if a value has been entered or not (set the attribute `readonly="readonly"` on the input if you don't want users to insert random data manually into your input.

I currently used the generic name submitbutton with the click function, replace that with your  or button that you have.

As for the return false or e.preventDefault(), that will prevent your form from submitting when the field is left empty

```
$('#submitbutton').click(function(e){
   if(!$("#inputdate2").val()){
       alert("you didn't pick a date");
       return false; // might not work if it doesn't use e.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

Comment: where you want it to check if input has been entered or not, maybe on the click of one of your buttons, I don't really have enough information to know that

Comment: yes onclick a button.. in html when user click submit button. if date not selected he should be notified ..

Comment: @babar I don't know what your submit button is called but I edited my code, put it into your $(document).ready(function(){});